# Is that formula provable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following formula provable?:

$0<a\Longrightarrow(a<b\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{b}<\frac{1}{a})$ where $a,b$ are real numbers

Comment: Not quite. $a>0$ and $a<b$ implies $1/b<1/a$, but the converse isn't true. $1/b<1/a$ is also true if $b<0$ and $a>0.$

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the additional hipothesis that $0<b$, yes: then also $0<ab$ and you can divide the equation $a<b$ by $ab$ and multiply the equation $\frac1b<\frac1a$ by $ab$.

Comment: Hence the following formula is provable:
$0<a\wedge 0<b\Longrightarrow(a<b\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{b}<\frac{1}{a})$